# Facebook decoding Json

Tags: php, json

I want to decode the location of a user.
Suppose

```
"id": "100000564553314",
"name": "Adi Mathur",
"location": {
      "id": "106487939387579",
      "name": "Gurgaon, Haryana"
}
```

I am using the Script to get the name  but location is giving me an error

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
. $params['access_token'];

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

echo $_SESSION['name']=$user->name;  // WORKS 
echo $_SESSION['fbid']=$user->id;     // WORKS

echo $_SESSION['location']=$user->location[0]; // ERROR
echo $_SESSION['location']=$user->location->name; // ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using:

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true);
```

This will ensure that $user is an associative array rather than an object. Then you can set your $_SESSION variable like so:

```
$_SESSION['name']=$user['name'];
$_SESSION['fbid']=$user['id'];
$_SESSION['location']=$user['location']['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the second parameter `assoc` as `true` in `json_decode`:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents(...),true);
```

This will return an array rather than an object. Then you can use array notation `[]` rather than object operators `->`